# VSCode not compiling c++

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, compilation

Im running Ubuntu MATE and i program in C++. I wanted to transfer to vscode so i installed it. But overall i cant really compile or debug anything. This works in terminal to run a code.

```
g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.o 
./HelloWorld.o
```

But if i want to go through button to compile this thing [happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyCMR.png). What should i do? Im adding launch.json down below.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "cpp - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: cpp build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody in the future wonder what was the solution, compile c++ under linux with g++ and then press ctrl+f5. That one solved my problem, couldnt figure it out for 2 days.